# R read_excel: How to associate range=cell_cols and cell_type

Tags: r, excel, multiple-columns, cell

This is the question.

I have an excel file to import with read_excel function.
42 columns. Firts two columns are Date and Time, the following, from 3 to 42, data (numeric).

I want to select two ranges of columns, es `range=cell_cols(c('A:B', 'C:AP'))` and associate them to two different col_types, es `col_types=(c('date','numeric'))`.
Avoiding to types 2 `date` and 40 times `'numeric'`.

I tried this code: `read_excel("D:/R/File_xls/TOF_Bioquar/July_Fluxes.xlsx",range=cell_cols(c('A:B','C:AP')),col_types=(c('date','numeric')), sheet = 1)`, but it gives me an error. **Error: Sheet 1 has 42 columns, but `col_types` has length 2.**

I searched online before writing here, but I did not found solution.
It is possible?
Thanks

Comment: I wrote:```read_excel("D:/R/File_xls/TOF_Bioquar/July_Fluxes.xlsx",col_types <- c(rep('date', 2), rep('numeric', 40)), sheet = 1)```

It gives me another error: Error in as.cell_limits.character(range) : length(x) == 1L is not TRUE

Comment: Sorry try: `col_types = c(rep('date', 2), rep('numeric', 40))`